# append material ui snackbar to body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a component that is only visible when a user hovers over it. In that component I have a button which allows the user to add something to the local storage. If the button is clicked the component is removed from the DOM. This works fine, but I want to show the user a toast when the action is completed. The issue is that the toast is also removed when the button is clicked because it's part of that component:

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Overlay backdrop_path={movie.backdrop_path}>
      <div>
        <AddMovie onClick={() => addMovie(movie)}>Add movie to your watchlist</AddMovie>
      </div>
    </Overlay>
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      onClose={handleClose}
      TransitionComponent={Slide}
      message="Movie has been added"
    />
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

I rather not put the `Snackbar` toast in a different component because this component is responsible for adding a movie to the local storage, and I don't want to do a lot of props lifting etc to get the result.

So I thought, maybe it's possible to append the `Snackbar` element to the body instead of the components element. This way if the components element is removed the `Snackbar` should still be visible. Not sure if this logic will actually work though.

Is it possible to append a element/component to another part of the DOM structure, if so: how?

Answer (score 0):

Seems appending rendered elements into other DOM elements isn't difficult:

```
return ReactDOM.createPortal(
  <Snackbar
    open={true}
    onClose={handleClose}
    TransitionComponent={Slide}
    message="Movie has been added"
  />,
  document.body
);
```

But this element also gets removed the instant the component that renders it is removed. Which makes sense. So it looks I need to render the `Snackbar` in a different element. Shame.

// edit. By using Redux it might be possible to create a global state for using the Snackbar elements > https://browntreelabs.com/snackbars-in-react-redux-and-material-ui/

// edit#2. https://github.com/iamhosseindhv/notistack this package makes it a lot easier and is supported by the Material UI team.